# Excel: Starting macro on other worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a button on one worksheet (let's call it worksheet1) and I want to run a macro on a different worksheet if it's clicked.
My code looks like this:

```
Sub Makro1()
Dim try As String
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Worksheet2")

'
' Makro1 Makro
'

'
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUM(R[-50]C[8]:(INDIRECT(""K"" & (MATCH(TODAY(),R[-50]C[7]:R[94]C[7],0) + 6))))"
    ws.Range("INDIRECT(""C"" & (MATCH(TODAY(),R[-50]C[7]:R[94]C[7],0) + 6))").Select
End Sub
```

Since I have never worked with Excel before, I don't know, whats wrong...
The goal is to add the formula to the cell (C__) whose index number is the same as today's date (comparsion in cells J7 to J151).

Comment: **1.** `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1` This will put the formula in the activesheet. Perhaps something like `ws.Range("A1").FormulaR1C1...` Change `A1` to the relevant destination cell. **2.** `ws.Range("INDIRECT(""C"" & (MATCH(TODAY(),R[-50]C[7]:R[94]C[7],0) + 6))").Select` You need to supply a proper range name when you are using `Range()`

Comment: Thanks, the first part helps but for the second part, what can I use instead of Range()? Since I need this macro the add the formula to a new cell every day